# How to literally translate this: 能够追得上我们赶了三天路的疲劳的身体?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

“那是为了让我们的灵魂，能够追得上我们赶了三天路的疲劳的身体。”

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 26. I need your help in its literal translation.

那是(that is)为了(for the sake of)让(letting, allowing or making)我们的灵魂(our souls)，能够(can)追得上(?)我们(we or our)赶了(?)三天路(3 days road)的疲劳的身体(tired bodies)

As you can see, the 追得上 and 赶了 are unclear to me.

追得上 means to pursue up? to chase after up? to hunt up? to track up? What exactly is its meaning?

赶了 means to catch up with? to overtake? to hurry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

追 = chase

追上 = catch up

追得上 = able to catch up

赶了 = has been hurried

> [1.那是][2.为了][3.让][4.我们的灵魂]，[5.能够追得上][6.我们{赶了三天路的}疲劳的身体]

> [1. That's] [2. for] [3. allowing] [4. our souls] [5. to be able to catch up with] [6. our tired bodies] {that have been hurried on the road for three days}

With "allowing", "to be able to" is redundant

- 那是为了让我们的灵魂，能够追得上我们赶了三天路的疲劳的身体
- That's for allowing our souls to catch up with our tired bodies that have been hurried on the road for three days

Answer (score 1):

After travelling for a long distance you will usually feel exhausted, sluggish, listless. If one believes that the soul is what drives all body actions, then it is as if the body has lost its soul -- it was lost sometime during the journey and needs time to "catch up" and return to the body. That's what this sentence is about.

Hence 能够追得上我们赶了三天路的疲劳的身体 = "(the soul) to be able to catch up with the body, which has travelled for 3 days and is now exhausted".